# PHP integration with Java

Tags: java, php, architecture

I'm developing an application that uses PHP as the front-end and Java as the back-end. The issue here is that the java jar file will be obfuscated to protect IP, how can I still integrate PHP with an obfuscated java back-end.

Will creating simple JSON command help?

I need your advice and suggestions.

Thank you.

Clarification

1. I'm using PHP for the front-end(UI) it makes developing the UI more flexible as the application will have many UI, it will run in a web browser using Apache and MySQL.
2. The PHP and java will run on thesame server.
3. I'm yet to implement how they will talk to each other that why I need your advice.
4. Developing all the UI's in java will not be flexible and will make the application more complex.

How can I use a shared database to communicate between the PHP and java code?

What standard way can I use to send request to the java server despite the fact that the java server code is obfuscated?

Logic or example will be appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Are both of these applications on the same server? How does obfuscating the jar protect the IP?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by front-end and back-end here, and how they'd talk to each other? ... and ... start by getting it to work without the so-called obfuscation. :-)

Comment: This sounds like a very complicated thing to implement. Why not use Java all the way through? Why use PHP here at all?

Comment: your assumption #4 is simply wrong. see GWT for a great java UI implementation. certainly no more complex than smashing Java and PHP together

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. There are different ways they can communicate, such as sharing the same database, or by sending requests to the java server.

But honestly, I can't be more specific without more details from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing, but if I'm understanding you correctly you want to call java code directly from your php code.

One option would be [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/), which is an implementation of PHP in java. It has bindings for calling java directly from PHP code.